# GWT GAE Upload through Blob

Tags: gwt, file-upload, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

If I'm using GWT File widget and form panel, can someone explain how to handle upload on blobstore on google application engine??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [gwtupload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/). There are [examples on how to use it with GAE Blobstore](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/source/browse/#svn/trunk/GwtUpload/gae/src/main/java/gwtupload/server/gae%253Fstate%253Dclosed).

Answer (score 1):

Google blobstore is specifically designed to upload and serve blobs via http. Blobstore service (obtained using `BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService()`) generates http post action for you to use in the html form. By posting file to it you upload your blob to the blobstore. When you generate this action you provide a path to the handler (servlet) where you have access to uploaded blob key:

```
Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("data");
```

Note, that "data" is the file field in your form. All you have is a key to the blob (your file). From here you take control - you can save this key for later and/or immediately serve the  blob on a page (using key):

```
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);
```

Of course, for details see Google [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html).

One nice feature of the blobstore that it's integrated with Google Mapper (rudimentary map-reduce) service (work in progress) which lets you process files uploaded as blobs line by line: http://ikaisays.com/2010/08/

Comment: On the client side, what should i set the form's action to

Comment: form will look like: 
`String uploadUrl = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload");
out.println("<form action='" + uploadUrl + "' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>");`
where /upload is a mapping to my servlet that handles things after blob saved to blobstore (1st code snippet in the answer).

Comment: I'm using the GWT GAE upload, it is successfully uploading giving me  servlet.gupld?blob-key=lSPbUItHU2v6jKhMUrcF7gDQUlofRktEPkocaPpO2Y4wwOQwd1-Tt51HUpDom3HPKAix3xxMbUD3eFnpQoLVIvXwYuJ_i7EU30RCTVwRJf_fvg but when i setting using url, it is ouputting file not found