# Uploading Files in GWT without GAE and Apache Commons

Tags: java, file, google-app-engine, gwt, upload

I would just like to ask if there is a way to upload files in GWT WITHOUT using the Google App Engine and Apache Commons archives? I've been searching for ways to upload files in GWT but all of the solutions I find all make use of these two. I would just like to know if there is a way, because our app won't work if we use GAE and Apache Commons... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the simplest would be (assuming you are saving files to Blobstore):

1. On GWT side use [`FileUpload`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html). Here is [an example](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~FileUpload) on how to use it.
2. On GAE side use [BlobStore upload handler](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Uploading_a_Blob).

The other option would be to use [gwt-upload with GAE upload handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6516296/248432).

Comment: ^ Thank you for your answer, but, would it be possible for it to not require the use of the GAE? Or is there no way to do it without using the GAE?

Comment: Are you running this on GAE or not? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The web app we have isn't run on GAE. I want to give our web app the functionality to upload videos for the use of our users, but I have to do it without using GAE.

Answer (score 0):

GWT does not have such feature. You need to use some existing library or handle multipart form submits by yourself (FileUpload class). There is for example a gwtupload library which I have used and it worked pretty fine (but it is based on commons-upload AFAIR). There are other libs for sure.

http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/